# "Problems parsing JSON" when creating an issue with github API and Python requests

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, github-api

When I try to create an issue with the python requests module, it returns the problem `{"message":"Problems parsing JSON","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}`

here is the code I use:

```
user = <My user>
pswd = <My password>
ses = requests.Session()
ses.auth = (user, pswd)
issue = {"title": "Hello World",
         "body": "omg",
         "assignee": <My user>,
         "milestone": None,
"labels": ["label", "friend"]
}
l = json.dumps(issue)
r = ses.post("https://api.github.com/repos/<My user>/<My repo>", params=l)
```

Of course I replaced the things in `<>` for the actual user and repo, I put it like that here for privacy reasons

Comment: Try with `user` instead of `<My user>`

Comment: I use my actual user and everything there, I put `<My user>` for privacy reasons (naturally), thanks for the comment, I will clarify it

Comment: Oh okay. Then I guess the problem come from the `None` value. Do you have any idea what the server expect precisely ?

Comment: It expects an int for `milestone`, but it doesn't work when I set it to an number either. The rest expects a string, and `labels` expect an array of strings

Comment: Are you trying to use [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/milestones/) ? If so, your URL miss `/milestones` at the end.

Comment: Is not that, i'm trying to create an issue

Answer (score 2):

Use `json` parameter to send JSON document and `POST` to `/repos/:owner/:repo/issues`  :

```
import requests
import json

user = "username"
pswd = "password"
repo = "your-repo"

ses = requests.Session()
ses.auth = (user, pswd)

issue = {
    "title": "Hello World",
    "body": "omg",
    "assignee": user,
    "milestone": None,
    "labels": ["label", "friend"]
}

issue_url = "https://api.github.com/repos/" + user + "/" + repo + "/issues"

r = ses.post(issue_url, json = issue)
```